# ¿Por qué mi página me arroja estos errores?

Tags: javascript

Analicé mi página en una consola para ver si tenia errores en Javascript y me arrojó 2 errores:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
Source file: at line: 150, column: 5103
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Source file: at line: 65, column: 372
```

Este es el código que me arroja el primer error:

```
var text = ["texto 1", "text 2", "text 3", "text 4"];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);
$('a').attr('href', text[rand].replace(/\s/g, "-"));
```

El otro error, no tengo idea de donde proviene.

[Aquí dejo un link para que observen mi script en funcionamiento](http://output.jsbin.com/zobowulalo)

Comment: Vas a tener que poner tu código completo para ver qué puede estar pasando. Al menos poner la línea donde se intenta hacer un replace de null. Además, me parece que estamos hablando de un codigo minificado, digo, porque tiene más de 5000 columnas

Comment: Si exactamente lo minifique, y ya agregue el código donde me arroja el primero error.

Comment: Lo curioso es que *pareciese* que rand te genera un índice superior a la longitud de `text` pero eso no puede ser porque `Math.floor` siempre redondea hacia abajo. Saca `text[rand]` y ponlo arriba de la línea problemática para descar eso: `var texto = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];` e imprime `texto`.

Comment: De echo ya lo había intentado así, y el resultado es igual.

Comment: Y el código sin minificar tira el mismo error?

Comment: Si, de echo hago los dos análisis a la vez, minificado y sin minificar.

Comment: Cuando dices que el resultado es igual, ¿quieres decir que ni siquiera imprime `texto`?  Si el código no es tan largo, ponlo en pastebin para poder observarlo más a fondo.

Comment: Si me genera el texto aleatorio, pero me marca ese error. Lo extraño es que es `jsbin`, `pastebin` y `jsfiddle` no marca absolutamente nada. Pero en esta consola jsconsole.com si me marca el error y otros errores mas que no marca en que linea se encuentran

Comment: Los errores son claros: El 1º indica que `var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);` está dando un resultado nulo y el 2º indica que tu programa excede el número de llamadas hechas a la pila. Este tipo de error es debido casi siempre a que el programa entra en un bucle infinito. Sin ver el código en su conjunto es más difícil ayudarte. Aunque es posible que estés usando mal tu random. Prueba: `var rand = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];`

Comment: Y como podría averiguar que esta generando el bucle infinito, y si ya lo he intentado muchísimas veces, incluso poniendo una cantidad especifica en vez de utilizar `length`, y aun así me arroja ese error que me esta causando dolor de cabeza, pero por lo menos me genera el texto aleatorio.

Comment: Te pedí que pusieras el código en pastebin para poder verlo y testearlo. De lo contrario no pasamos de la especulación.

Comment: Listo amigo, ya puse un link de jsbin.com

Comment: El bin funciona correctamente. [He refactorizado](https://jsfiddle.net/22zb47ew/) un poco tu código para hacerlo más legible. Fuera de eso, todo funciona bien.

Comment: Bueno creo que tendré dejar eso aun lado, ya me canse de buscar el error. Y gracias por el demo refactorizado, me gusto y creo que adaptare así mi código. :)

Comment: Ya intentaste con text.eq(rand)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te hice un snippet mostrando el comportamiento de rand y href en 100 iteraciones. Ninguna causa error, ni aunque haga 1000 ni 10000 iteraciones.

```js
var i=0,
    text = ["texto 1", "text 2", "text 3", "text 4"],
    timerId;

timerId = window.setInterval(function() {
  i++;
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);
  
  $('a')
  .text('Iteración '+i+', rand es '+rand)
  .attr('href', text[rand].replace(/\s/g, "-"));  
  
  if(i>=100) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }
},100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Soy el elemento a</a>
```

Pienso que la única respuesta posible (y con eso admito que esta no es una respuesta completa y merezco muchos downvotes) es que en alguna parte se esté sobreescribiendo el valor del array `text` o se le esté pusheando uno o más elementos nulos. Por ejemplo:

```js
var i=0,
    text = ["texto 1", "text 2", "text 3", "text 4"],
    timerId;

timerId = window.setInterval(function() {
  i++;
  
  if(i==10) {
    text.push(null);
  }
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);
  
  $('a')
  .text('Iteración '+i+', rand es '+rand)
  .attr('href', text[rand].replace(/\s/g, "-"));  
  
  if(i>100) {
     clearInterval(timerId);
  }

},100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#">Soy el elemento a</a>
```

Hay varias posibilidades, pero la primera pista es que no está apuntando a un índice inexistente, pues ello arrojaría

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Cuando específicamente está diciendo

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

Por la misma razón tampoco es posible que text se haya sobreescrito a un string, número, booleano u objeto, ya que el error sería distinto.

Comment: Se agradece tu ayuda amigo, y pues aun no encuentro el problema, ya hasta Reescribí mi código y nada. Pero bueno ya que, así lo tendré que dejar hasta dar con la raíz del problema.

Answer (score 0):

Pues no veo que de error el fragmento de código que presentas.

¿Podrías dar más datos?

```js
var text = ["texto 1", "text 2", "text 3", "text 4"];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length);
$('a').attr('href', text[rand].replace(/\s/g, "-"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>Test anchor link</a>
```

Comment: Hola Litta, bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te comento cordialmente que cuando publicas una respuesta es para ofrecer una **solución** a la pregunta del OP. Trata de **no publicar respuestas que necesiten aclaración del OP**. Cuando tengas suficiente reputación (50), podrás comentar para pedir detalles, indicar cosillas rápidas, etc. Te invito a [hacer el tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y a consultar la guía [Cómo responder](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hola @GustavoGarcía, yo conozco StackOverflow en inglés y pensé que era igual. Solo intentando ayudar. Anyway... AnimationsNow Sería de gran ayuda si te apoyaras de un (https://jsfiddle.net/) con tu código, así siempre es más fácil encontrar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas veces el error está en otra parte. Creo que este es uno de esos casos.

Comment: De acuerdo con @A.Cedano. De hecho el error de Maximum call stack size exceeded supongo se dá en otra parte muy diferente del fragmento que nos presenta. Esperemos feedback :)

Answer (score -4):

creo que esta chocando en la parte del regex del replace haber intenta con esto

```
               var mapObj = {
                    one: "hola",
                    two: "mundo",

                };

                var limite_text = counter.Texto.replace(/hola|mundo/gi, function (matched) {
                    return " ";
                });
```

y debugea return para que veas lo que te manda en la consola

Comment: Gracias amigo, y pues aun así me da el mismo error.

Comment: se me hace raro que te mande error al replace probablemente tengas un script con algún error de sintaxis o una etiqueta script mal acomodada

Comment: Ya hice varias comprobaciones anteriormente, analize el html, el css, el php y el javascript, y solo el javascript me arroja errores.